# Reduce data usage in an application supports offline-mode

Tags: java, android, synchronization

I am working with an application which has `offline mode`. In order to do that we store the information in a local `SQLite` Database and using `Content Provider` which provides a wrapper around the SQLite, and `sync` it every once in a while with the data from the web service. 
We are also keeping the images which are taken by user on the sdcard and send them to the server during the sync service.

The problem is `bandwidth` and data usage. In Android 4.0+, we have a section in device setting named `Data usage`. It is showing too much data usage and it annoyed the users.

My first question is : Do you think using [ProGaurd](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) which is a tool to shrink the code, can have any impact on reducing the Data Usage?

I would appreciate if you share any experience and suggestion with me in order to reduce the Data usage in such an app.

Addenda:

1 - User login to the system and during first sync sqlite file generated and transferred from REST (initialization).

2 - We have sync-status flag for entries in database. If record(using json string for data) or picture is not synced, it will transfer to the REST during sync and status-flag get updated.

3 - An updated database file receives from REST and merge with the current database on the phone in the sync service (if initialization is already done).

Comment: ProGuard will reduce the size of the APK file, but will not change data usage when the application activities are running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ProGuard has nothing to do with the amount of data you send/receive from a server. ProGuard can shrink and obfuscate code (thus making your APK smaller).

You need to analyze the data you send and receive. There is no silver bullet here that will magically solve any bandwidth issues you may come across in an app. You need to ask yourself several questions and take action depending on your answers:

**What kind of numbers are we talking about?**
[In 2011 the average bandwidth use of an app was around 10MB per hour](http://www.virginmediabusiness.co.uk/News-and-events/Business-blog/2011/Apps-driving-mobile-data-traff/). There are probably more recent surveys if you search a bit. Are you far above the average number? If not, then I don't think you have to worry too much.

**How often do you send and receive data?**
If it's a real-time app that absolutely require live data then there's little you can do. If it's not a real-time app maybe you can reduce the frequency of send/receive or wait and collect more data before sending it to reduce overhead? If you're sending many small chunks of data you'll get a lot of overhead in HTTP headers and so on. Hold on to the small chunks a while longer and send them in one go to change the data to overhead ratio.

**Can you change the protocol?**
Maybe you can send data over a socket instead of HTTP to reduce overhead? By your description it doesn't sound like this would work in your case.

**Can you compress data before sending it?**
[Make sure that your server GZips data before sending it to the client](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression). There is **a lot** to gain by doing this.

**Can you use another data format (binary, json, xml, custom)?**
You mention that you use JSON. JSON usually/always perform better than XML, so you're already good there, but maybe you can send data in another format that is even more compact?

Comment: ur questions should have been in comment

Comment: @britzl, I put an addenda at the end of my question. the sync service is working every 15min as default, but user can change it manually in the app setting. I `receive` a full database file in initialization(first login) and updated db in the next syncs. I `send` data in json format.

Comment: I've updated my answer. The questions I asked were meant as my answer. There's a bunch of questions you need to ask yourself if you are worried about bandwidth use. I've added some actions you can take for each of the questions I asked. Remember that there's not silver bullet to magically reduce bandwidth use in apps. You need to deal with this on a case by case and app by app basis

Comment: Thanks @britzl, and +1 for you thorough answer.